# Building multidimensional array with iteration

Tags: matlab

I have an array with size x(21,1), I do the following operation to get the result without any iteration.

```
n=11;
m=11;
R=zeros(m,m,n);
for i=1:n
z=x(i:i+m-1);
R(:,:,i)=z*z';
end
Rz=sum(R,3)/n;
```

Now, I have a variable that change from j=1:50, to have x(21,1,50), how I can implement this iteration for this code.

Any help I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What do you mean "without any iteration" when your sample code has a for-loop? What is the "result" that you are trying to get? Your code doesn't have `x` defined, what is it supposed to be, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: to clarify the question. This code is a part of m-script, x have been defined previously and the result is a matrix with size (21,1). The above code is to get the value of specific index  that is z with size (11,1) then perform the covariance matrix to z with 11 layer so I get the matrix R(11,11,11). Now, I want to repeat this operation 50 times of z(21,1,50), to get R(11,11,11,50).

Comment: Put the code in a function and use a `for` loop. That is why loops are there.